# html form with required fields

Tags: php, forms

I have a form that is currently working but want to add php code to the "post" file so some fields in the html form are required otherwise a message displays.

heres my html code at the moment.

```
<form action="contact.php" method="post">
      <input type="text" class="main" name="cf_name" value="Name (Required)" size="31" />
      <br />
      <br />
      <input type="text" class="main" name="cf_company" value="Company" size="31" />
      <br />
      <br />
      <input type="text" class="main" name="cf_phone" value="Phone (Required)" size="31" />
      <br />
      <br />
      <input type="text" class="main" name="cf_email" value="Email (Required)" size="31" />
      <br />
      <br />
    <textarea type="text" name="cf_text0" cols="34" rows="3" class="main">Message</textarea>
      <br />
      <input type="image" src="images/send.jpg" height="16" width="41" border="0"
      alt="Submit Form" />
</form>
```

and heres my php code

```
<?php
$field_name = $_POST['cf_name'];
$field_company = $_POST['cf_company'];
$field_phone = $_POST['cf_phone'];
$field_email = $_POST['cf_email'];
$field_message = array($_POST["cf_text0"],);

$mail_to = 'callum@colmandesigns.co.nz';
$subject = 'A & J Print - Contact Form '.$field_name;

$field_message="From: {$field_name}
Company: {$field_company}
Phone: {$field_phone}
Email: {$field_email}
Message: {$field_message[0]}";


$headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $field_message, $headers);

if ($mail_status) { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Thank you for the message. We will contact you shortly.');
        window.location = 'index.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
else { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Message failed. Please, send an email to craig@colmandesigns.co.nz');
        window.location = 'index.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

I want to have the Name, Phone and Email fields required.

Thanks,
Callum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

//contact.php

```
<?php
    $filled = true;
    $required = array("cf_name", "cf_email", "cf_phone"); //all the required fields

    //Cycle through each field and make sure its filled

    foreach ($required as &$value) {

        if($_POST[$value]==""){
            $filled = false;
        }
    }

    //If there are any fields not filled out, send the user back to the form
    if (!$filled){
        header("Location: http://ajprint.co.nz/index.php?error=true"); 
    }

    else{
        $field_name = $_POST['cf_name'];
        $field_company = $_POST['cf_company'];
        $field_phone = $_POST['cf_phone'];
        $field_email = $_POST['cf_email'];
        $field_message = array($_POST["cf_text0"],);

        $mail_to = ''; //put your email
        $subject = 'A & J Print - Contact Form '.$field_name;

        $field_message="From: {$field_name}
        Company: {$field_company}
        Phone: {$field_phone}
        Email: {$field_email}
        Message: {$field_message[0]}";

        $headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

        $mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $field_message, $headers);

        if ($mail_status) { 
            echo "
                <script language=\"javascript\" type=\"text/javascript\">
                    alert('Thank you for the message. We will contact you shortly.');
                    window.location = 'index.html';
                </script>";    
        }

        else {
            echo "
                <script language=\"javascript\" type=\"text/javascript\">
                    alert('Message failed. Please, send an email to craig@colmandesigns.co.nz');
                    window.location = 'index.html';
                </script>";
        }
    }

?>
```

//index.php

```
<form action="handler.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" class="main" name="cf_name" placeholder="Name (Required)" size="31" />
        <br />
        <br />
    <input type="text" class="main" name="cf_company" placeholder="Company" size="31" />
        <br />
        <br />
    <input type="text" class="main" name="cf_phone" placeholder="Phone (Required)" size="31" />
        <br />
        <br />
    <input type="text" class="main" name="cf_email" placeholder="Email (Required)" size="31" />
        <br />
        <br />
    <textarea type="text" name="cf_text0" cols="34" rows="3" class="main">Message</textarea>
        <br />
    <input type="image" src="images/send.jpg" height="16" width="41" border="0" alt="Submit Form" />
</form>
```

I replaced all the "value" tags with "placeholder" so that even if the user did not clear the field, it would not get marked as filled

Comment: Tell me if it works (*crosses fingers*). No reason it shouldn't... worked for me :)

Comment: Its nearly there. did you receive emails? because im not (i have added the email correctly)

Comment: Yeah, I received them... is the mail function enabled?

Comment: Yes, I think im getting them. thanks anyway dude. just quickly im copying all the code you gave me correct I dont need to worry about the //Form Code you added a while back in the index.php file?

Comment: yay! *claps hands* have a great night, bud :)

Answer (score 5):

In HTML you can just put "required" attribute for making input tag required !
For example

```
<input type="text" id="someId" name="IP" placeholder="IP" required tabindex="1">
```

or

```
<input type="text" id="someId" name="IP" placeholder="IP" required="true" tabindex="1">
```

But consider that, IE and Safari have not supported this tag until now!

Answer (score 3):

**Using PHP:**

```
//Form Processor Code

$filled = true;
$required = array("cf_name", "cf_email", "cf_phone"); //all the required fields

//Cycle through each field and make sure its filled
foreach ($required as &$value) {
    if(!isset($_POST[$value])){$filled=false;}
}

//If there are any fields not filled out, send the user back to the form
if (!$filled){
    header("Location: http://mysite.com/form.php?error=true");
}

//Form Code

//Notify the user that the form needs to be filled completely
if(isset($_GET['error'])){
    echo "Sorry, but the form was not properly filled out.";
}
```

The problem with this is that you'll need to store the form values in the session before going back, otherwise the user will have to re-enter the entire form. It's better for the user if you use Javascript, but watch out for browsers with JS disabled.

**Using Javascript:**

Either use

```
onBlur
```

when the user has finished typing in a field or use

```
onClick
```

when the user tries to submit the form.

A good tutorial on this can be found [here](http://www.developertutorials.com/tutorials/javascript/javascript-form-validation-correction-050412-1290/).

Comment: The code will work, but seems a bit unintuitive.  Maybe something a little more straightforward?  Create an empty array of strings, check each input value if it exists (and meets business rules), add an error message to the array of strings if the validation fails, then at the end if the array is not empty then stop processing and display the errors to the user.

Comment: @David its been updated since you read it, but I'm just trying to give him an idea on how to do it...

Comment: Actually, since your update the code will no longer work.  `$done` will only be false in this case if the _last_ value fails validation.  In your example, if `var1` fails validation but `var2` passes then the code won't respond to that.

Comment: @MihirSingh: Should work now :)  But I still _highly_ recommend taking a more "Clean Code" approach.  `$done` as a variable name doesn't convey much, and the conditionals aren't really expressing their intent.  Maybe I'm just being nit-picky, but it's worth a little extra effort to make the world a better place to code :)

Comment: @David I was actually working on cleaner code... And you're not being nit-picky at all. I prefer clean code too :)

Comment: Im very confused. I dont know much about php.

Comment: @Callum, what don't you understand from the code above? I can explain it, but I need to know what to explain... :)

Comment: Sorry Mihir, im guessing from the code im not touching anything in the html. where am i putting the code your provided me? do I need to edit anything in the code i already have?

Comment: @Callum, the code titled 'Form Processor Code' should go at the beginning of your php code (the form processor). Then, the code titled  "Form Code" should go at the beginning of your html form (change the extension to php and wrap it in <? ?>). But remember, if the user is sent back, they may have to refill out the form from scratch unless you implement sessions.

Comment: @Callum what exactly do you not understand? And why not use the javascript tutorial? If you prefer PHP, I can implement sessions for you if you give me a few minutes.

Comment: not working - i must be doing something wrong. ive added the Form Processor Code right at the top of my contact.php file. as for the html page i have changed to .php and added the "Form Code" just above the <form action="contact.php" ....> I have wrapped the "Form Code" in <? ?> or am i wrapping the WHOLE file?

Comment: @Callum, no... just the form code... Is the code that you posted redacted or in full form?

Comment: everything in my original post is in full form.

Comment: @Callum ok, give me a second.

Comment: @Callum no, wait... your HTML form is redacted, right? Could you post the full code? I could implement it for you.

Comment: the error is Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in /var/www/vhosts/ajprint.co.nz/httpdocs/index.php on line 126

Comment: @MihirSingh heres the index.php code

http://codepad.org/t0ctyOqx

and heres the contact.php

http://codepad.org/fqP5Gbw1

Comment: @Callum, try the fix that I posted right above your comment. If it doesn't work, I'll implement it myself

Comment: Yes it works.. kinda. I can now see the file http://ajprint.co.nz/index.php

but when you click submit it still sends the email even when you dont type anything in the required fields

Comment: Nup, same thing. I appreciate the help if you can be bothered then nevermind.

Comment: Wait!!!! @Callum..... I haven't done fully yet, but I had a "brain fart" while writing the code! The problem is in your html form ;)

Comment: You use value="the value" to set the text like "Email (Required)"... So, even if the user doesn't type something in, there already is a value i.e. Email (Required).... remove the value tag and it should work :)

Comment: Ok, I got it to completely work... To avoid clutter, I'm putting the completed version in another answer.

Comment: @Callum... welcome :) Nothing else for a 16 year old to do on a wednesday :) Could you please accept the new answer?